# c# double - why is the answer always 0?

Tags: c#, double

I have a double that when assigned is always coming back as 0.0, but should not happen.

The code I have is

```
double test = (27096140 / 27216140);
```

The answer to this should be 0.9955....

I am not using the double primitive type correctly?

Cheers

**Edit**

Of course, I was using int and no floating points.
Knew it would be a matter of common sense.

Comment: You must cast the numbers to float or double.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually performing integer division here because the 2 numbers are whole. That forces the result of the calculation to be `int` which truncates the precision so you end up with `0`.

You need to tell the compiler you are actually working with floating-point numbers and not `int`'s, just adding a floating point to one of the numbers should fix this e.g.

```
double test = (27096140.0 / 27216140);
```

Alternatively, you could actually declare the numbers as doubles

```
double a = 27096140;
double b = 27216140;
double test = (a / b);
```

Or even cast the number in the calculation

```
double test = ((double)27096140 / 27216140)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using integer division, you should use floating-point division:

```
double test = (27096140.0 / 27216140);
```

Answer (score 2):

Beacuse you're using integers instead of doubles. Use:

```
double test = (27096140.0d / 27216140.0d);
```

Answer (score 1):

The numbers 27096140 and 27216140 are ints, so the result of the division is also an int: 0.
Then this is cast to a double: 0.0